# Why is System.paxos growing up and how to decrease it?

Tags: cassandra

I'm a newbie with Cassandra and we've started to use it. Sounds good.

Found that table `paxos` in `System` is using more space than our data. We are going to transfer all our data from SQL to Cassandra and this will be around 2 TB.

Will this table grow in the same way and, if yes, how to decrease it or maybe it is safe to truncate it?

```
System.paxos::::
Table: paxos
                Space used (live): 2144801786
                Space used (total): 2144801786
Exdata.data::::
Table: trnsfr
                Space used (live): 1742847712
                Space used (total): 1742847712
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cassandra uses `system.paxos` table for Lightweight transactions (IF clause i.e `IF NOT EXISTS`)**

> Lightweight transactions with linearizable consistency ensure transaction isolation level similar to the serializable level offered by RDBMS’s. They are also known as compare and set transactions
>
> Cassandra implements lightweight transactions by extending the Paxos consensus protocol, which is based on a quorum-based algorithm. Using this protocol, a distributed system can agree on proposed data additions/modifications without the need for a master database or two-phase commit.

**If you use an IF clause in CQL statements, such as INSERT is consider as lightweight transactions.**

For example :

```
INSERT INTO customer_account (customerID, customer_email) 
VALUES ('LauraS', 'lauras@gmail.com')
IF NOT EXISTS;

//or

UPDATE customer_account
SET    customer_email='laurass@gmail.com'
IF     customerID='LauraS';
```

Both of the above statements are Lightweight transactions. For both statement Cassandra make sure linearizable consistency using Paxos consensus protocol. It uses the system `system.paxos` table internally.

Note : **Paxos make sure linearizable consistency at the cost of four round trips. That sounds like a high cost—perhaps too high, if you have the rare case of an application that requires every operation to be linearizable. But for most applications, only a very small minority of operations require linearizability, and this is a good tool to add to the strong/eventual consistency They've provided so far.**

Source :
https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_ltwt_transaction_c.html

Comment: Ashraful, thank you very much for such complete answer. But is it possible to truncate it? 
Regards,
Evgeny

Comment: When there is no Lightweight transactions running, you can truncate the table